# Render UL and LI in search result display template

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, display-template

I am customizing sharepoint search result web part and trying to render Ul and li tags, following are my control and item template html files

my control template

[image: Control template]

my item template

[image: Item Template]

result

[image: result]

but output file rendering some extra div elements inside UL tags, I don't want highlighted divs.

Answer (score 1):

The Grouping divs are coming from the `Group_Default.html` file.  If you want to remove those  I would assume you'll have to edit the `Group_Default.html` file as well.

[image]

Comment: Can I configure my web part to not to use grouping at all?

Comment: I was wondering that too, but didn't see any such option.  I think the functionality is there for things like Result Blocks?  Not sure.